# SQS size limitation, but using DB no limitation in Lumen

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-sqs

I've been using Database as Queue Driver ( `RDS` ) with Lumen and I got no limitation, after moving to `SQS` as Queue Driver I got limitation error ( using the same job ).

Before moving to SQS I did research about how long the size of a row in mysql / message in SQS, and I found that significantly SQS has the largest size.

Mysql row size according to its documentation (65,535 bytes).
SQS size is ( 256 KB ).

So how to overcome this memory limit in SQS or even how Mysql has the least row size and there is no exception there, how sqs is hitting the limit although it has a bigger limit?

```
public function handle()
    {
        $result = $this->queue;


        $template = $result['queue']['template'];
        $subject = $result['queue']['subject'];
        $person = $result['queue']['person'];
        $locale = $result['queue']['locale'];
        $app_url = $this->app_url;
        if (isset($person['email']) && $person['email'] != '') {
            Mail::send($template, ['data' => $result['queue']['data'], 'person' => $result['queue']['person'], 'app_url' => $app_url, 'locale' => $locale], function ($message) use ($person, $subject) {
                $message->to($person['email'])
                    ->subject($subject);
            });
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**
`$data['data']` has a user object with some relations loaded.

Comment: the better question is: how are you hitting those limits ? can you share the code & errors you're getting ?

Comment: @N69S yes exactly, how sqs is hitting the limit although it has a bigger limit.

Updated